# Logstash nested JSON Parse

Tags: json, ruby, logstash

I have a Logstash configuration which receives JSON input from Kafka and sends it to Elasticsearch Output.

Received JSON has the following structure:

```
TrackingData: {
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "method": "GET",
    "requestDateTime": "2017-11-07T16:12:02.635",
    "duration": 5104684,
    "status": 200
}
```

I would like to add the `status` value as a new field so that it can later be displayed in a new column when viewing EL data using Kibana. I understand that for this I should include a `mutate` `filter` in the Logstash config.

What should the Ruby string be in order to get the `status` value out of the JSON structure and into a new field?

My Logstash config is currently as follows:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => ["kafka:9092"]
        topics => "test-topic"
        group_id => "test-topic-group"
    }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "root_field" => "%{[message]}"
            "status_field" => "%{[message][TrackingData][status]}"
        }
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }   
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elk:9200"]
}
```

When a message is processed by Logstash, I can see the `root_field` parsed okay in Kibana (I've added this field just to prove that the json is parseable) but the `status_field` is displayed as `%{[message][TrackingData][status]}` in Kibana (i.e. the parsing String must be incorrect).

How should the parsing String be specified in order to get `status` value out of the example JSON structure above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were wrong. The first problem was the JSON itself being received that was wrong. `TrackingData` was not surrounded in `"`. Correct JSON should be like this:

```
"TrackingData": {
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "method": "GET",
    "requestDateTime": "2017-11-07T16:12:02.635",
    "duration": 5104684,
    "status": 200
}
```

Second, I've added `codec => "json"` and removed `filter` code block in the Logstash's config:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => ["kafka:9092"]
        topics => "test-topic"
        group_id => "test-topic-group"
        codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }   
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elk:9200"]
}
```

Now, received JSONs' key/values are being parsed into separate fields and therefore can be displayed in separate columns in Kibana as necessary (or filtered out if not needed at all).

[image: Kibana screen grab showing JSON fields in separate columns]